# Role hierarchy not having Partner Manager and Partner Executive Role

Tags: account, user, role-hierarchy, roles, partner

I created a user by convert lead to contact and then enabling the partner account and enabling the partner user.

I was able to create the user but when I edit the user to select a different role I see only  Partner User in the dropdown.

As per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_partner_roles_overview.htm&type=5) from Salesforce I should have three roles created for that account. i.e  Partner User/Manager/Executive.

I am using a developer edition salesforce account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_default_roles.htm&type=5) documentation to set up the default number of roles.
This has to be increased from communities settings